# Using Valgrind in large, multimodule, fortran program

Tags: memory, fortran, gdb, valgrind, darwin

I'm currently finishing up a development project in the Quantum Espresso (QE) code. It's a large (>100k loc) fortran package, with many modules all linked together. I'm trying to find a painful memory bug, and have turned to valgrind to find the issue. It appears to have found bugs but, unfortunately, the valgrind output below is less than clear on where exactly the error is, and it doesn't give any important line numbers.

```
==10233== Invalid write of size 8
==10233==    at 0x100520518: __mbdvdw_module_MOD_mbdvdw_tgg_complex (in /Users/tmarkovich/bin/pw.x)
==10233==    by 0x100555A88: __mbdvdw_module_MOD_mbdvdw_check_quantity_dh (in /Users/tmarkovich/bin/pw.x)
==10233==  Address 0x103131248 is 8 bytes after a block of size 1,728 alloc'd
==10233==    at 0x1011814AB: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==10233==    by 0x1005547B0: __mbdvdw_module_MOD_mbdvdw_check_quantity_dh (in /Users/tmarkovich/bin/pw.x)
==10233==    by 0x1003D56E4: v_of_rho_ (in /Users/tmarkovich/bin/pw.x)
==10233==    by 0x1000F540B: electrons_scf_ (in /Users/tmarkovich/bin/pw.x)
==10233==    by 0x1000F6E18: electrons_ (in /Users/tmarkovich/bin/pw.x)
==10233==    by 0x10032AA28: run_pwscf_ (in /Users/tmarkovich/bin/pw.x)
==10233==    by 0x1000010BB: MAIN__ (pwscf.f90:30)
==10233==    by 0x100B67C1F: main (pwscf.f90:14)
```

Beyond this, addr2line gives thoroughly unhelpful output:

```
▶ gaddr2line -e pw.x 0x100520518
??:0.
```

Note, it looks like some of the debugging symbols exist because we see pwscf.f90:30, and we see stuff like "__mbdvdw_module_MOD_mbdvdw_tgg_complex" in the backtrace, but it'd be super useful to know which part of the function is causing the issue.

I have compiled QE given the following flags with gfortran 4.9:
FFLAGS         = -Og -g -pg -fopenmp -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -finit-real=nan -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,zero,overflow

Is there any way to compile QE such that it generates all the debugging symbols, so that I can get more readable and informative output from valgrind? I thought all I needed was the -g flag, but it appears that I might need more? Is there a way to get addr2line to give more informative output? what about valgrind?

It's also worth nothing that GDB has the same exact behaviour.

edit:
I made sure to put -g in both CFLAGS and LDFLAGS such that my make file looked like:

```
CFLAGS         = -Og -g $(DFLAGS) $(IFLAGS)
F90FLAGS       = $(FFLAGS) -x f95-cpp-input -fopenmp $(FDFLAGS) $(IFLAGS)   $(MODFLAGS)
FFLAGS         = -Og -g -pg -fopenmp -Wall -Wextra -Warray-temporaries -Wconversion -fbacktrace -ffree-line-length-0 -finit-real=nan -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,zero,overflow
LD             = mpif90
LDFLAGS        = -g -pthread -fopenmp
LD_LIBS        =
```

This resulted in a compilation statement of:

```
mpif90 -Og -g -pg -fopenmp -Wall -Wextra -Warray-temporaries -Wconversion -fbacktrace -ffree-line-length-0 -finit-real=nan -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,zero,overflow -x f95-cpp-input -fopenmp -D__GFORTRAN -D__STD_F95 -D__FFTW -D__MPI -D__PARA -D__SCALAPACK -D__OPENMP   -I../include -I../iotk/src -I../ELPA/src -I. -c mbdvdw.f90
```

Another run of valgrind with all the above info results in:

```
==30486== Invalid write of size 8
==30486==    at 0x1002735ED: __mbdvdw_module_MOD_mbdvdw_tgg_complex (in /Users/tmarkovich/bin/pw.x)
==30486==    by 0x100290F58: __mbdvdw_module_MOD_mbdvdw_check_quantity_dh (in /Users/tmarkovich/bin/pw.x)
==30486==  Address 0x1037989f0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1,728 alloc'd
==30486==    at 0x10092B4AB: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==30486==    by 0x10028FEE2: __mbdvdw_module_MOD_mbdvdw_check_quantity_dh (in /Users/tmarkovich/bin/pw.x)
==30486==    by 0x1001D4567: v_of_rho_ (in /Users/tmarkovich/bin/pw.x)
==30486==    by 0x10007C0BE: electrons_scf_ (in /Users/tmarkovich/bin/pw.x)
==30486==    by 0x10007D385: electrons_ (in /Users/tmarkovich/bin/pw.x)
==30486==    by 0x10018B30B: run_pwscf_ (in /Users/tmarkovich/bin/pw.x)
==30486==    by 0x100001157: MAIN__ (pwscf.f90:30)
==30486==    by 0x1004EC496: main (pwscf.f90:14)
```

Comment: -g should work, but you can try -ggdb and even different formats (drwarf2 or whatever, I don't know osx for this).

Comment: I realized that I only had -g in FFLAGS and LDFLAGS, but not CFLAGS. I'm rerunning valgrind now to see if adding -g to CFLAGS helps. Also, I tried -ggdb and that didn't appear to help any.

Comment: A write of size 8 is probably a double precision float. You seem to write after the end of an array of size 1728 bytes (216 elements). Try to find where you write in a double precision array of 216 elements in the mbdvdw_tgg_complex module. Your loop bounds are probably wrong. And 216 elements can be multidimensional, like (54,4) for example...